# How do I "re-group" a pig relation?

Tags: apache-pig

Assume I have an input file `input.dat` that looks like this:

```
apples 10
oranges 30
apples 6
pears 5
```

Now, when I load, group, and project the data:

```
sources = LOAD 'input.dat' as { a:chararray, b:int };
grouped = GROUP sources BY a;
projection = foreach sources generate flatten(group), SUM(sources.b);
dump projection;
```

I get the following:

```
apples 16
oranges 30
pears 5
```

Now, I want to "re-group" the data where the `SUM(sources.b)` is below some threshold into a single line. As an example, if the threshold was 20, I would get:

```
other 21
oranges 30
```

because the sum for both "apples" and "pears" was below the threshold of 20.

It seems to me that I can follow a couple of different approaches:

1. Use the `SPLIT` operator on `grouped` to create two relations: `above_threshold` and `below_threshold`. Then project `below_threshold` to replace the value of `a` with "other" and regroup. Finally `UNION` that result together with `above_threshold` and then run the final projection again.
2. Or, follow the original script exactly, but when creating `projection`, generate `a` conditionally (based on `SUM(sources.b)`), then re-group `projection` (to group all of the "other" rows together), and then project again (to flatten the re-grouped data).

Is one of the above approaches clearly better than the other? Or is there another approach that will be more efficient or easier to maintain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 is better. This is because option 1 only has to pass around `below_threshold` data into a M/R record count; while in option 2, you are regrouping everything, it seems like.

Also, there are a few good things about approach 1, most notably:

- The `below_threshold` count is going to be pretty fast because you only need 1 reducer and the combiner is going to do wonders with only one key.
- Depending on your application, you don't *need* to `UNION`. You can just output to two locations, and then "union" by treating them as the same output externally from pig. For example, you can still do `hadoop fs -getmerge my_out/*/part-r-* output` to grab both outputs.

So, I see your Pig script looking like:

```
sources = LOAD 'input.dat' as { a:chararray, b:int };
grouped = GROUP sources BY a;
projection = foreach sources generate flatten(group) as n, SUM(sources.b) as s;
SPLIT projection into above_threshold if s >= 20, below_threshold if s < 20;
dump above_threshold;

below_grouped = GROUP below_threshold BY 'other' PARALLEL 1;
below_projection = FOREACH below_grouped GENERATE group, SUM(below_threshold.s);
dump below_projection;
```